# Post и get запросы в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Доброе утро. Есть вопрос связанный с отправкой get и post запросов. Разбираю примерчики с метанита и немного не понятно. Вот пример кода get запроса:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Книжный магазин</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>Распродажа книг</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Название книги</p></td>
                <td><p>Автор</p></td>
                <td><p>Цена</p></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var b in ViewBag.Books)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><p>@b.Name</p></td>
                    <td><p>@b.Author</p></td>
                    <td><p>@b.Price</p></td>
                    <td><p><a href="/Home/Buy/@b.Id">Купить</a></p></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

И action в контроллере обрабатывающий этот запрос:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Buy(int id)
{
    ViewBag.BookId = id;
    return View();
}
```

И post запрос с его обработчиком:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Покупка</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>Форма оформления покупки</h3>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.BookId" name="BookId" />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Введите свое имя </p></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Person" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Введите адрес :</p></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="Address" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Отправить" /> </td><td></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

[HttpPost]
        public string Buy(Purchase purchase)
        {
            purchase.Date = DateTime.Now;
            db.Purchases.Add(purchase);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return "Спасибо," + purchase.Person + ", за покупку!";
        }
```

В связи с этим у меня есть несколько вопросов.

1) Как мне сделать так что бы отправить get запрос другим способом, таким как в этом примере отправляется post? То есть сменить там тип запроса на гет в form и сделать то же самое но этим способом, либо с помощью эквивалентного этому коду html-хелпера beginform.

2)Если например будет 2 метода либо get либо post относящихся к одной вьюхи и называющихся одинаково как я смогу выбрать к какому я обращаюсь.

3)Почему в это примере именно таким образом разделены запросы? Можно же например то что тут отправляется get запросом сделать наоборот post, а то что тут отправляется post-ом, отправить get-ом.

4)В этом примере в методе `Buy(Purchase purchase)` метод принимает модель:

```
public class Purchase
    {
        public int PurchaseId { get; set; }
        public string Person { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }

        public Purchase()
        {
            Books = new List<Book>();
        }
    }
```

И так как в post запросе атрибуты полей совпадают с полями модели, не приходится нечего делать и mvc сам знает как ему собрать данные в модель. А если например атрибуты полей в post запросе будут называться по другому, как сделать что бы их так же собрать в нужную мне модель так как мне нужно?

Код view:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Название книги</p></td>
                <td><p>Автор</p></td>
                <td><p>Цена</p></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var b in ViewBag.Books)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><p>@b.Name</p></td>
                    <td><p>@b.Author</p></td>
                    <td><p>@b.Price</p></td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="post" action="/Home/Buy">
                            <input type="hidden" value="@b.Id" name="Id" />
                            <table>
                                <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Отправить" /> </td></tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
```

Код контроллера:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        Context db = new Context();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Book> books = db.Books;
            ViewBag.Books = books;

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Buy(int id)
        {
            ViewBag.BookId = id;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public string Buy(Purchase purchase)
        {
            purchase.Date = DateTime.Now;
            db.Purchases.Add(purchase);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return "Спасибо," + purchase.Person + ", за покупку!";
        }
    }
```

Как указать к какому контретно методу обращаться?

Answer (score 3):

1. `@Html.BeginForm("actionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Get)`.
2. Uri запроса будет сопоставлятся с маршрутами из RouteTable и типом запроса.
3. Потому-что запросы типа POST не являются идемпотентеными. http://www.restapitutorial.ru/lessons/idempotency.html
4. Необходимо реализовать "кастомный" привязчик(ModelBinder) реализуя интерфейс IModelBinder. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.imodelbinder?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Comment: Помогло с первым пунктом вопроса удалось отправить с помощью такого вида. Но осталась вторая часть вопроса. Как всё таки выбрать к какому методу обращаться? Я в контроллере сделал оба метода post. И во вьюхе index сделал метод отправки пост и он теперь не может выбрать к какому ему обращаться. А ваш ответ по второму пункту не понял, объясните пожалуйста поподробнее. Код вьюхи добавил в конец вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

1)Обычно GET-запросы,  это те запросы которые возвращают `View`, а POST-запросы отправляют какие-либо данные с вашей `View`. Если на форме стоит атрибут `method="post"`, то в контроллере будет искаться именно метод c `[HttpPost]`, отсутствие `method="post"` говорит о том, что это [get-запрос](http://htmlbook.ru/html/form/method).

2) Для этого вы указываете к какому именно методу контроллера вы обращаетесь через `action="название метода"`.

3) Потому что, первый метод возвращает View "Buy",

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Buy(int id)
{
    ViewBag.BookId = id;
    return View();
}
```

а второй метод **получает данные** с этой View, обрабатывает их (добавляет данные в БД) и что-то возвращает.

```
[HttpPost]
public string Buy(Purchase purchase)
{
    purchase.Date = DateTime.Now;
    db.Purchases.Add(purchase);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return "Спасибо," + purchase.Person + ", за покупку!";
}
```

Comment: Дмитрий спасибо за ответ, с первым пунктом разобрался а по второму не понял. Я сейчас в конце вопроса привёл пример, я написал метод post из вью и в контроллере 2 post метода с одинаковым названием. Как выбрать к какому конкретно я хочу обращаться? Куда нужно дописать asp-action немного не понял подскажите пожалуйста. И разве asp-action это не asp.net core? У меня если что asp.net mvc

Comment: @Андрей Для чего вы используете одинаковое название методов контроллера? Одинаковые названия методов контроллера применяются в [полиморфизме](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism) и тогда среда исполнения будет выбирать, тот метод, который имеет соответствующий тип переменных. P.S. MVC- это паттерн, а не среда исполнения.

Comment: @Андрей используйте разное название методов, назовите второй метод Add. используйте 'tag-helper' ведь вы работаете в ASP.NET и запишите так:  '<form method="post" asp-action="Add" asp-controller="Home">.

Comment: @Андрей точно, не обратил внимание что не Core. Тогда так: <form method="post" action="/Home/Add">.

Comment: Дмитрий, они одинаково называются потому что и вью так же называется, что бы mvc мог связать вью и контроллер по дефолту. Да и это пример с mvc вот так и оставил. Просто хотел узнать можно ли выбрать конкретную перегрузку, потому что по набору параметров почему то не определяет.

Comment: @Андрей, здесь есть пример использования одинаковых методов [ссылка](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/774807/Attribute-Routing-in-ASP-NET-MVC-WebAPI)

Comment: @WebMorda почитал, понял что это делается роутом, но там не совсем понятно как это делать. Вы не могли бы привести пример как это в моём случае будет? Не могу понять какой роут нужно написать что бы запрос понял к какому ему конкретно методу обращаться.